# Have to split dataframe column based on length value in another column

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, split

I have pandas dataframe df in below format

```
Title                                               
ABCABCABC   
ABCDABCDABCD                            
ABCDEABCDEABCDE             
ABEABEABE
```

I want to split the `Title` column into 3 equal parts.

Expected output:

```
Title1            Title2          Title3
ABC                ABC             ABC
ABCD               ABCD            ABCD 
ABCDE              ABCDE           ABCDE
ABE                ABE             ABE
```

please help me know how to do it.

I tried to get length, but not sure how to split based on length value.

```
  df['len'] = df.Title.str.len()
```

Comment: What happens when the Title isn't evenly divisible by 3?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the builtin `textwrap` module.

---

```
import textwrap

pd.DataFrame(
  [textwrap.wrap(el, len(el)//3) for el in df['Title']]
).add_prefix('Title')
```

```
  Title0 Title1 Title2
0    ABC    ABC    ABC
1   ABCD   ABCD   ABCD
2  ABCDE  ABCDE  ABCDE
3    ABE    ABE    ABE
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way:

```
pd.DataFrame([np.split(np.array(list(i)),3) for i in df.Title]).applymap(''.join)
```

---

```
       0      1      2
0    ABC    ABC    ABC
1   ABCD   ABCD   ABCD
2  ABCDE  ABCDE  ABCDE
3    ABE    ABE    ABE
```